# How do I make sure imported files are uploaded to Google App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python

I have an application whose entry point is defined in Emily.py.
Emily.py imports EmilyBlogModel.py and EmilyBlogModel.py imports EmilyTreeNode.py.

When using appcfg.py to upload this app to Google App Engine, how do I make sure that the all my files are uploaded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The update process doesn't really do any analysis of the code, it just uploads everything it finds under the root folder (where your `app.yaml` lives), as [noted in the docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadinganapp#Python_Command-line_arguments):

> The update action creates or updates the app version named in the app.yaml file at the top level of the directory. It follows symlinks and recursively uploads all files to the server.

Only exception are [skipped files](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Python_app_yaml_Skipping_files), which you can personalize to achieve the opposite.